# Nested JsonArrayRequests using volley Android

Tags: android, arrays, android-volley, nested-loops

*Hello Everyone,*
I m working on a survey App which inputs different types of answers for questions like single choice answers (radio button), multi choice answers (checkbox) or free text answers (EditText), I want to display all of the questions and related answers to users and for retrieving the data from MySQL I have used nested json array requests so I could be able to loop through questions and for each question loop through its options if it has.

Here is my codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // questions json url
    private static final String url = "http://yakja.net/survey/fetch_questions.php";
    // options json url
    private static final String url2 = "http://yakja.net/survey/fetch_options.php";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public JSONArray myArray;
    public JSONObject obj,obj2;
    public RequestQueue request;
    public ViewGroup rdbtn;
    LinearLayout main,questionLayout,radio,editLayout,check,checkLayout;
    TextView ques;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest questions = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

        // Parsing json
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {

                 obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.questions_view);
                    questionLayout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_radio, null);
                    radio = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.radio, null);
                    editLayout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_edittext, null);
                    check = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_check,null);
                    checkLayout = (LinearLayout) check.findViewById(R.id.check_add_layout);
                    ques = ((TextView) questionLayout.findViewById(R.id.q_title));
                    ques.setId(obj.getInt("q_id"));
                    ques.setText(obj.getString("q_text"));
                    main.addView(questionLayout);
                    rdbtn = (ViewGroup) radio.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);

                if(obj.getInt("q_type_id")==1 || obj.getInt("q_type_id")==2) {
                    JsonArrayRequest options = new JsonArrayRequest(url2,
                            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONArray response2) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, response2.toString());
                                    hidePDialog();
                                    myArray = new JSONArray();
                                    myArray=response2;
                                 try {
                                     if(obj.getInt("q_type_id")==1){
                                         for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length(); j++) {
                                             obj2 = myArray.getJSONObject(j);
                                             if (obj.getInt("q_id") == obj2.getInt("q_id")) {
                                            RadioButton button = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
                                             button.setId(j);
                                             button.setText(obj2.getString("option_text"));
                                             button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
                                             rdbtn.addView(button);

                                             }
                                         }
                                       main.addView(radio);
                                     }
                                     else if(obj.getInt("q_type_id")==2)
                                     {
                                         Log.d("question type is", String.valueOf(obj.getInt("q_type_id")));
                                         for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length(); j++) {
                                             obj2 = myArray.getJSONObject(j);
                                             if(obj.getInt("q_id")==obj2.getInt("q_id")) {
                                                 CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                                                 checkBox.setId(obj2.getInt("o_id"));
                                                 checkBox.setText(obj2.getString("option_text"));
                                                 checkBox.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
                                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams checkParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                                 checkParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                                                 checkParams.gravity = Gravity.START;
                                                 checkLayout.addView(checkBox, checkParams);
                                             }
                                         }

                                         main.addView(check);
                                     }
                                 }
                                 catch (JSONException e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                 }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                            hidePDialog();
                        }
                    });

                    request =  Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                    request.add(options);
                }

                else if(obj.getInt("q_type_id")==3)
                {
                    Log.d("question type is", String.valueOf(obj.getInt("q_type_id")));

                    main.addView(editLayout);
                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                   }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });

        request =  Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        request.add(questions);
        }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Now the problem is that the radio buttons and check boxes are not displaying because the object of the first json array request which is the questions array data `(obj)` is null or empty inside the second request block.
I have searched alot to find the solution of this problem but unfortunately couldn't.

I would be very thankful if anybody could help me fix this problem.
Thank you in advance!

**Updates**

*This is the questions json response*

```
[{"q_id":"1","date_posted":"2016-11-02 16:13:44","q_type_id":"1","survey_id":"1","q_desc":"Self efficiency test","q_text":"I am strong enough to overcome life's struggles"},{"q_id":"2","date_posted":"2016-11-02 16:13:44","q_type_id":"1","survey_id":"1","q_desc":"Self efficiency test","q_text":"I can handle the situations that life brings"},{"q_id":"3","date_posted":"2016-11-02 16:18:39","q_type_id":"2","survey_id":"1","q_desc":"","q_text":"Which foods do you like the most?"},{"q_id":"4","date_posted":"2016-11-02 16:18:39","q_type_id":"3","survey_id":"1","q_desc":"","q_text":"who is your inspiration in your life?"}]
```

*This is the options json response*

```
[{"o_id":"1","option_text":"Strongly Agree","q_id":"1","option_no":"1"},{"o_id":"2","option_text":"Agree","q_id":"1","option_no":"2"},{"o_id":"3","option_text":"Disagree","q_id":"1","option_no":"3"},{"o_id":"4","option_text":"Strongly Disagree","q_id":"1","option_no":"4"},{"o_id":"5","option_text":"Strongly Agree","q_id":"2","option_no":"1"},{"o_id":"6","option_text":"Agree","q_id":"2","option_no":"2"},{"o_id":"7","option_text":"Disagree","q_id":"2","option_no":"3"},{"o_id":"8","option_text":"Strongly Disagree","q_id":"2","option_no":"4"},{"o_id":"9","option_text":"Manto","q_id":"3","option_no":"1"},{"o_id":"10","option_text":"Aashak","q_id":"3","option_no":"2"},{"o_id":"11","option_text":"Qabli","q_id":"3","option_no":"3"},{"o_id":"12","option_text":"bolani","q_id":"3","option_no":"4"},{"o_id":"13","option_text":"pizza","q_id":"3","option_no":"5"}]
```

*And this is the `obj.toString()` result inside the second json request block*

```
{"q_id":"4","date_posted":"2016-11-02 16:18:39","q_type_id":"3","survey_id":"1","q_desc":"","q_text":"who is your inspiration in your life?"}
```

And the above result shows repeatedly in each loop , you can see that the `q_type_id` is 3 always which should be 1 or 2.

Comment: please post the complete JSON response. How does it look like?

Comment: Post your json response

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getInt("key")` , use `optInt("key", fallback_value);` So in such scenario if you don't get the key still you will get some value like `null or fallback_value`. 
And if you only want to use getInt(), you should first check with `has("key")` to check if the key is present in the JSONObject.

```
     obj = response.optJSONObject(i);
    if (obj!= null) {
     //Continue
    }
```